# Is Ember Inspector released yet (for Chrome)?

Tags: ember.js

I have read several times about the **Ember Inspector** and habe also seen videos on yotube  of it, e.g. [example video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B9leRf5kuo).

Does anyone know, if it is available yet or when it will be available. This will make debugging so much more convenient, i want to try it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the current version by cloning the [github project](https://github.com/tildeio/ember-extension)

found via http://cgcardona.github.com/2013/02/15/playing-around-with-the-ember-inspector/

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, it's live!

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi

*(blah blah... stupid minimum answer length requirements... blah blah)*

Answer (score 0):

It's released. check below link
But i still get confused how to use it on my site.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi